# Android: start service when date and time setting is changed by user

Tags: android, date, service, time

I am implementing a session manager for my application. Each time an activity is resumed, it checks if the session is active. If it is, the activty starts, else it displays another activity authenticating the user. Whenever an activity is paused, it sets the current time in the session manager. The session is active when there is a running activity, or the last timestamp set in pause is no older than x minutes.

The problem with this is that if the user changes time settings, it is possible that the session looks active again, due to the timestamp part.

I want to solve this with a service that is started when the date and time setting is changed (I know there are intents describing this event) and resets the session. It only needs to run if the application is still running, because the session manager will be a static class which loses state when the process is finished.

How can I create shuch a service?

Comment: vincent, see this maybe helpful : [Date and time change listener in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822713/android-start-service-when-date-and-time-setting-is-changed-by-user)

Comment: Thank you, I've already read that, but it looks like an inactive question and I need further information. I need to know how to use that solution (or any other) if I have multiple activities.

Comment: Now I see the question is quite pointless - anyway, thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need a service for this. You should be able to implement a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest for `ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` (and possibly `ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED`, as I am uncertain if that will affect your session). In `onReceive()`, check and see if you have a session. If you do not, then the user changed the time when your application was not running, and you are OK. If you do have a session, then you can take whatever steps you want at this point (e.g., invalidate the session).

Comment: Is onRecieve() to be implemented in an activity? I have multiple activities and no matter which is active the fuction resetting the session should be called. That's why I thought a service would be approprioate, beacuse I don't need any graphical activities, only a quick function call.

Comment: @Vincent: "Is onRecieve() to be implemented in an activity?" -- no. `onReceive()` is a method you implement on `BroadcastReceiver`. "That's why I thought a service would be approprioate, beacuse I don't need any graphical activities, only a quick function call." -- except that you **still need the `BroadcastReceiver`** since the only way you can find out about these events is via a broadcast `Intent`. Hence, you do not need a service.

Comment: Well, I wasn't really aware of the nature and purpose of broadcast recievers, now I am and read the corresponding page of the developer guide. I see this is exactly what I need and makes the question quite dumb, anyway, thank you (again) for your patient guidance!